# "Sorry Ubuntu * has experienced an internal error" /usr/bin/compiz

Tags: compiz, virtualbox

I installed 13.04 as a virtual machine using VirtualBox from Oracle. When it was done doing the install, it says that it needs a reboot. After the reboot, I got this message:

> Sorry Ubuntu 13.04 has experienced an internal error /usr/bin/compiz

I'm not sure what it means and how to resolve it.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! We need more hardware information to help you, can you look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/14008/i-have-a-hardware-detection-problem-what-logs-do-i-need-to-look-into) and then edit your question adding the information. Also, have you checked the BIOS for settings relating to virtualization?

Comment: @Seth it is a VM!

Comment: After a fresh install it is alwasy a good idea to update your guest OS by running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` there. This may get bug fixed.

Comment: @guntbert Yes I realize that, some computers have virtualization stuff in the BIOS that helps, and I can't run Unity 3D inside Unity 3D because of graphics issues.

Comment: It's a virtual machine that I'm running on VirtualBox 4.2.16. The 13.04 Ubuntu that I installed is 32bit. The host machine is Win 7, 64bit with 8GB ram and about 600GB free disk space. It's an HP laptop with Intel Core i5. Using nvidia geforce gt 630m 1gb. When I start the virtual machine (Ubuntu), I get the login page. After I put my login info, I get a black screen. Eventually the error message comes up. I clicked Continue then I'm back to a black screen. Just a mouse cursor and nothing else.

Comment: Also, before the first restart, it did automatically install a bunch of updates too after I put my password on the authorization box to let the updates to continue. The error message was already showing when the updates message came up. I'm able to get to the Terminal with the Ctrl+Alt+F1. I got: Ubuntu 13.04 Me-Ubuntu tty1 Me-Ubuntu login: * Starting [OK] Should I do the "sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade" at this point?

Comment: I installed 12.04 instead and that worked just fine. I guess the 13.04 has some UI issues with VirtualBox.

Comment: @user190521 I'm experiencing exactly the same issue that you are describing. Have yet to find a solution.

Comment: You should install Guest Additions from terminal and enable 3d acceleration for this VM.

Answer (score 7):

It just means there's been a problem with compiz, which is the window manager on Ubuntu. If you don't experience any problems, then it has corrected itself. However, you can file bugs if you want to tell developers what happened so that they can fix it.

If your desktop is working properly, you don't have to worry about it. But you'll probably want to install Virtual Box Guest Additions, which will provide drivers for your graphics and other things.

Comment: +1 You *definitely* want to install the guest additions, especially if you are seeing problems.

Comment: In casw you have problems with your graphics driver even when you have installed guest addutiins think about using vm ware player

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I solved it by selecting into VirtualBox properties "Activate 2D acceleration". After that the desktop is working.